# Importing CSV to SQLITE

Tags: excel, sqlite

I am just starting a new spreadsheet of recipes (in Google Docs) that I will eventually be importing into a SQLite database.

My question is, how can I best input the data into this spreadsheet so that it can be readily imported into SQLite when I'm finished?

My main concern is that many of the recipe fields (list of ingredients, list of directions) are obviously going to have many separate lines per field (i.e. one cell of the spreadsheet will have multiple lines of information in it).

Can anyone suggest the best way to enter these newlines into the spreadsheet so that it will correctly import when I'm done?

I will be manually loading the csv into the database and then using it as a static database in an iOS app. This will be a one-time loading of data, so I'm open to importing it using whichever method would be easiest.

Any thoughts or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What programming language/environment are you using to load the csv data into SQLite?  That's really the important part here.

Comment: I will be manually loading the csv into the database and then using it as a static database in an iOS app. This will be a one-time loading of data, so I'm open to importing it using whichever method would be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the end result you're trying to achieve.

The basic idea is to break the recipe down into simpler pieces, for example "ingredients" and "steps".  You can go the full [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) route to gain maximum query-ability/extensibility if you want.  The idea is that you store the data in broken down form and "reconstitute" it later with SELECT queries.

The approach you seem to be thinking of - putting a "list" of values in one field - isn't how *relational* databases like SQLite are designed to work.

I don't know what you're trying to do in the end, but perhaps a document-oriented database like CouchDB or MongoDB would be more suitable?

Comment: I know I could get better performance with broken down tables, but this is actually just for a simple iPhone app, hence the limitation to SQLite. I won't actually be doing any 'searching' of the database per se, just loading it into an array to display in the app.